# Cannot use $2 backreference in regex replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a javascript calculator using string.replace regex but I'm stuck on a problem.
For example my input is `10k`, I'm trying to replace the k with `000`.

So, I've made this regex that tries to replaces all occurences with the index of the letter `k` in the string `kmbt`.

`var answer = "10k".replace(/(\d+(?:[.,]+\d+)?)([kmbt])/gi, "kmbt".indexOf("$2"));`

When I console.log this, it returns -1, which is not what I want.

So changing the regex a bit to: `var answer = "10k".replace(/(\d+(?:[.,]+\d+)?)([kmbt])/gi, "$2");` It will correctly return `k`.

What I want it to return is `0` which is the position of the letter k in the string "kmbt". With this position I want to continue calculating but that is currently not relevant with this problem.

The problem is that apparently I cannot use a function in the 'replace' part of the regex.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem or how I can use functions in the 'replace' part?

**ANSWER**
You cannot make modifications directly in the regex, so you have to add a function as argument to the 'replace' part where you can make modifications with the result!
`var answer = rsn.replace(/(\d+(?:[.,]+\d+)?)([kmbt])/gi, function(match, p1, p2) {
    // do something with p1 and p2 and return something
    return p1 + p2 // for example
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function to replace strings like so:

```
"10k".replace(/(\d+(?:[.,]+\d+)?)([kmbt])/gi, function(match, p1, p2) {
    return p2;
});
```

`p1` and `p2` correspond to `"$1"` and `"$2"` in a normal replace. Any additional transformations or calculations can take place in the function before returning a result. In order to find the index of `p2` in the string `"kmbt"`, this should work:

```
"10k".replace(/(\d+(?:[.,]+\d+)?)([kmbt])/gi, function(match, p1, p2) {
    return "kmbt".indexOf(p2);
});
```

You can read more about how to do this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this helped me with finding a solution to my problem!

Answer (score 1):

First `indexOf` has nothing to do with a regexp pattern and thus `$2` would not be available. Second replace *can* take a function.

```
var SUFFIXES = {
  k: '000',
  m: '000000',
  b: '000000000',
  t: '000000000000'
};

'10k'.replace(/([\d.,]+)([kmbt])/, function (match, digits, suffix) {
  return digits + SUFFIXES[suffix];
});
```

Comment: Didn't know you couldn't use functions directly in the regex without a function first, thanks.